# Cassandra ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on SELECT * statement

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I have 2 column families with data that was inserted via a Java application using DataStax driver version 1.0.4. I CQLSH into one of the four nodes in the cluster using cqlsh 4.1.1 (Cassandra 2.0.5, CQL spec 3.1.1, Thrift protocol 19.39.0). I can perform a `SELECT *` from one column-family ("table_A") but not the other (table_X). I'm attempting to execute a `SELECT * FROM table_X` query. Instead of results, I get `TSocket read 0 bytes`. When I check the /var/log/cassandra/system.log, I see:

```
ERROR [Thrift:16] 2015-01-24 02:26:40,761 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 212) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Subsequent CQL commands (DESCRIBE, SELECT, USE, etc.) will return this same error. If I exit the session and CQLSH back into the node, I can then execute CQL commands again. If I add a WHERE clause to the query, it works fine. Granted, I have not went through the exercise of trying to query for every possible partition key to see if certain ones fail. I have a suspicion there is a corrupt row(s) in the column family, but I want to retain the data in the column family (I don't want to drop or truncate the column family).

Note that running a `SELECT * FROM table_A` works fine, it only errors out on `table_X`.

Has anyone seen this before or know what the cause is?

EDIT - Enabled debug logging and was able to get a stacktrace for this error:

```
ERROR [Thrift:3] 2015-02-06 14:21:50,800 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 212) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ColumnGroupMap.add(ColumnGroupMap.java:43)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ColumnGroupMap.access$200(ColumnGroupMap.java:31)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ColumnGroupMap$Builder.add(ColumnGroupMap.java:130)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processColumnFamily(SelectStatement.java:949)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.process(SelectStatement.java:854)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processResults(SelectStatement.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:202)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:172)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:58)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:188)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:222)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:212)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.execute_cql3_query(CassandraServer.java:1958)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql3_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:4486)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql3_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:4470)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT - Added the result from describing the keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE z WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '4'
};

USE z;

CREATE TABLE x (
  a int,
  b text,
  c text,
  d text,
  e text,
  f text,
  g text,
  h text,
  PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

CREATE TABLE y (
  i text,
  j text,
  k text,
  l text,
  m text,
  n int,
  o text,
  p text,
  q text,
  r text,
  s text,
  PRIMARY KEY (i)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: Was there a stack trace with that error message in system.log?

Comment: No stacktrace for this error.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `describe keyspace <keyspace name>` for the owning keyspace?

Comment: I added the describe keyspace output.

Comment: This looks like this C* Jira C-5138


Are you using Thrift?

  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5138

Comment: No Thrift, we use cqlsh.